# CSS Animation when visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on my portfolio website and was looking for inspiration on how to do a section of it. This site ->(https://www.thecraftsmen.tech/) looked amazing and I loved the animations on scroll, the ones under the what we do section. How would I go about coding this? I know of keyframe animations but I don't know how to trigger a transform: translate when it becomes visible. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: here's the keywords you need to google, "intersection observer"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Inspector while you are using the mentioned website, you can see what is going on in the "styles" when you are scrolling those elements.

Here is what I found,

1- When you are at the top of the page (they are not visible to you), the style is like this:

```
<div class="my-services-row__left" style="transform: translate(50%, 0%);">
     ....
</div>
```

2- when you are scrolling, it changes the parameters on the `translate` function. Also, it adds the `translate3d` function to its styles too. Something like this:

```
style="transform: translate(28.7655%, 0%) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

3- Finally, when you are scrolling enough, they finish in this position:

```
<div class="my-services-row__left" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
     ....
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, I understand what your saying and see the values changing but would you know how to enable those changes? Like what javascript I need in order to tell when you are going into visibility of the element and how to change it.

Comment: There is an event for that called "onScroll". Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp